# PopupMenu in wxPython with key press activated context menu items

Tags: wxpython, contextmenu, popupmenu

I have a GUI that creates a PopupMenu when I right click on a ListCtrl, and I'm able to select items from the PopupMenu with a (left) mouse click. In addition to this functionality, I'd like the context menu items to be able to be selected with specific key presses (e.g. "C" for "Clear", "A" for "Clear All").

How can I do this?

A snippet to show the idea-

```
self.listcontrol=wx.ListCtrl(self, wx.NewId(), style = wx.LC_LIST|wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL)
self.listcontrol.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN, self.OnFileRightDown)
...
def OnFileRightDown(self,e):
  men=wx.Menu()
  cmi = wx.MenuItem(men, wx.NewId(), 'Clear All...')
  men.AppendItem(cmi)
  self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnClearAll,cmi)
  self.PopupMenu(men,e.GetPosition())
```

I'd like to be able to press "A" when the context menu pops up to execute the OnClearAll method defined elsewhere.

I tried using an accelerator but couldn't get it to work.

Thank you.

Comment: No real solution, but maybe a hint in the correct direction: In your example, if you write instead of ``'Clear all...'`` the text ``'&Clear all (C) ...'``, it does react on pressing ``C``. It does however (at least on Windows/wxPython2.9) not show the C underlined (hence the ``(C)`` in the text.

Comment: @nepix32 I had actually tried this but since I didn't see an underline I didn't even test it. I don't mind the lack of underline as long as the functionality is there. Please post your answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried it out and learned something (tested on Win8/wxPython 2.9.5.1):

[image: Example popup]:

Mind the two different underline styles here. Both work with both the lowercase and uppercase letter.

- Applying the Accelerator by accelerator entry:

  ```
  menu = wx.Menu()
  item = wx.MenuItem(menu, self.popupID1, "One\tO")
  acc = wx.AcceleratorEntry()
  acc.Set(wx.ACCEL_NORMAL, ord('O'), self.popupID1)
  item.SetAccel(acc)
  menu.AppendItem(item)
  ```

Allows to get rid of the underscore.

- Applying the accelerator by modifying the menu item string with `&`:

  ```
  menu.Append(self.popupID2, "Two\t&T")
  ```

Comment: FYI, I'm on Win7/wxPython 3.0.1.1/Python 2.7.8 and the first method with accelerator doesn't work. (The culprit may be Python 2.7.8)